# Should I add lock to ignite cache as it will be read/write in different thread?

Tags: ignite

I have two thread, 
each thread add/modify the values of ignite cache, it likes:

```
cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("IniteTestCache")
valMap = cache.get(key)
```

get the item in value valMap(java map), handle it, and remove it and then
update the cache:
`cache.put(key, a)` to let the `valMap` items down,

in another thread:

```
cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("IniteTestCache")
valMap = cache.get(key)
```

add new items to `valMap`, and put it back to cache
`cache.put(key, a)` to add new items to it

Questions:
As i manipulation on the same cache with same key, should i add lock
to as:

```
lock()
value=cache.get(key)
modification to value
cache.put(key,value)
unlock()
```

or I use Atomic to the cache config to make ignite do this automatically for me,
or I need use TRANSACTIONAL to cache, and add lock to cache?

or there are some more better way to avoid lock to achive high performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `EntryProcessor` for this use case: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/jcache#entryprocessor

Comment: EntryProcessor use invoke which has a anonymous class, so when i use EntryProcessor in ignite service scope, i still need change the invoke used anonymous class to static inner class to avoid the not serialzie issue, right? thanks

Comment: Or i disable the peerclass loading, and explicit the jar file in the classpath to use the EntryProcessor ?

Comment: Examples in doc use anonymous classes for simplicity. They are allowed and you're free to use them, but the recommendation is to go with static classes instead in real applications as you can end up with hardly traceable issues. As I stated in a separate thread, not serializable  exception is not directly related to this anonymous/static class dilemma. BTW, peer class loading is supported for entry processors.